# Solutions to Weinberg's QFT Volume 1 Textbook

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, education

I have been reading through Weinberg QFT Volume 1 and attempting some of the problems on my own. Most of them are quite challenging, some I can't even finish on my own, and the problems that I $can$ finish I am not sure I have the right answer.

Is there a collection of solutions to Weinberg's book somewhere?

In particular, there is a problem in Chapter 6 - Feynman Rules, problem 6.5 which involves the use of a so-called Gell-Mann-Low Theorem in computing some vacuum expectation values of field operators. I have an answer and would like to check it.

Comment: AFAIK there is no solution manual available. They are generally available only for instructors, i.e. directly from the publisher to a staff member of a university which teaches the subject.

Comment: Excellent question! +1 ,which more than compensate the silly downvote given before by somebody else.